# Julia bitstring function and byte order

Tags: julia

I am running Julia 1.0.2 under Windows 8.1.

The following leads me to believe Julia treats my machine in "little-endian" fashion:

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.0.2"

julia> ENDIAN_BOM
0x04030201

help?> ENDIAN_BOM
search: ENDIAN_BOM

  ENDIAN_BOM

  The 32-bit byte-order-mark indicates the native byte order of the host machine. Little-endian
  machines will contain the value 0x04030201. Big-endian machines will contain the value
  0x01020304.
```

Based on above, the bitstring examples below make sense to me. Both have the least significant byte first, on the left, as I would expect for little-endian byte order:

```
julia> bitstring(1.0)
"0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

julia> bitstring(Char(1))
"00000001000000000000000000000000"
```

However, the following example seems to be in big-endian order, the least significant byte is on the right:

```
julia> bitstring(1)
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
```

Am I confused?  Any suggestions or explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question there are two separate issues.

`Char` representation is a custom design decision in Julia; the approach is that UTF-8 representation of a character is filled with `0`s on the right side to get 4 bytes (`UInt32`); you can see how the convesion happens e.g. in `Char(u::UInt32)` method definition.

For `1.0` and `1` you can see what are their little and big endian representations using `htol` and `hton` functions and you get:

```
julia> bitstring(htol(1))
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"

julia> bitstring(hton(1))
"0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

julia> bitstring(htol(1.0))
"0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

julia> bitstring(hton(1.0))
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111000000111111"
```

and all is consistent.

EDIT: see the explanation in the other answer what `bitstring` exactly does as it is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out hton() and htol().  The two responses are very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

`bitstring` cares about host byte order. In other words, 

`julia> bitstring(1)
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"`

is machine-independent, but

`julia> bitstring(hton(1))
"0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`

reflects your arch. Insert `hton` and `ntoh` if you parse packets.

This is because bitstring is most used for reality-checking code that uses flags, and `<<` et al operate on host byte order.

Comment: Nice answer. The other way to say what `bitstring` does is that it writes out a binary representation as a human would write it e.g. on a paper of a number padding it with `0`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helpful responses!